# Facebook Graph API - offline_access deprecated

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I`m a little bit confused about the Facebook Graph API.

First, I created an app on the developers page and then I autorized my app with a URL like this:

```
www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&type=user_agent
```

Ok... after this the page returned an URL like this one:

```
www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&expires_in=5171411&code=CODE
```

I realized that the ACCESS_TOKEN returned is always the same. So i used to search for users, like this:

```
graph.facebook.com/search?q=QUERY_SEARCH&type=user&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

I believe all the URLs above are correct.

My doubt is: i don't know how to use the long-live token (actually I dont even know if the returned token is a long-lived one). The same token is always returned for me when I use those URLs, so I always use the same ACCESS_TOKEN.

But as i read on the Facebook Graph page, a token can't be active forever anymore... they now expire.

How do I know if i have a long live token or not? When a token expire how can I "refresh" it?

I was trying to follow the documentation but I`m totally lost...

```
developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/
```

This page says that exists an "deprecate offline_acess" on the advanced settings menu... but it doens't!

So... i don't know how to manage tokens when they expire or how to know if i`m using a long-lived token

Comment: Facebook's Graph API Documentation is very confusing sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check when your access token is going to expire on [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token/).

You can get long-lived access tokens by using this api where you need to enter the short lived access token.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

where this will return the new long-lived access token. (which will have an expiry period of 2 months.)

Comment: Thank you Ayush, this one is very usefull... i`ll try to use in my code! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I think the general idea is that your access token will last a month or so, and when it stops working you need to request a new one.

I have a method like this to fetch a new one:

```
public static class GraphApiRequestProcessor
{
    public static string GetNewAccessToken( CancellationToken cancellationToken )
    {
        const string tokenUrlPattern = @"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials";
        string tokenUrl = string.Format( tokenUrlPattern, Settings.FacebookAppId, Settings.FacebookAppSecret );

        using( var client = new WebClient() )
        {
            // allows cancellation while executing request
            using( cancellationToken.Register( client.CancelAsync ) )
            {
                using( var data = client.OpenRead( tokenUrl ) )
                {
                    using( var reader = new StreamReader( data ) )
                    {
                        string response = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        int index = response.IndexOf( "=", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase );
                        string code = response.Substring( index + 1 );
                        return code;                
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Side note: even original "offline access" tokens had expiration (about a year I think), now it simply shorter expiration.

Comment: Alexei, thanks for your answer... but actually, a year ago my tokens didn't have expiration when I was using offline_access... i have one until now that never expires oO ... I don't know why... but i`m using it! =)